# Android - View not animating when out of screen (scrollview)

Tags: android, scrollview, android-animation

I have a LinearLayout wrapped by ScrollView. I have multiple rows of horizontally oriented LinearLayout with fixed number of columns of 3. It looks like the below.

[ ] [ ] [ ]

[ ] [ ] [ ]

[ ] [ ] [ ]

[ ] [ ] [ ]

[ ] [ ] [ ]

The issue happens when I have a large enough number of rows that goes out of screen. When I animate the ImageView that is positioned out of screen, it does not animate until I scroll it up to where that ImageView is visible on the screen.

I suppose this is because the view loses focus or it goes out of the available stack. Is there a way to figure out if this ImageView is not going to animate before I do so?

Comment: kind of off topic but why dont you just create a gridview instead of such a complex layout structure

Comment: I was originally using GridView. I changed it because I was getting unexpected behavior. I thought I would have better control implementing this way.